# Meteor flow router throwing blank pages

Tags: reactjs, meteor, flow-router, kadira

I am new to meteor flow router.

I am trying to implement kadira flow-Router and react-mounter into my custom User Account App. Though I have DOM and Mounter installed n my application, but I am getting that they are missing from my app.

After I start the server, the pages are becoming blank and not rendering.

I have attached screen shots along with this.

Please guide.

[image: App Crash Screen Shot]

[image: Flow Router Setup Screen Shot]
[image: Package Screen Shot]

Comment: did you run `meteor npm install`?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Answer (score 0):

You installed *react-mount* instead of *react-mounter*